# How to sync Calender with an android app

Tags: android, calendar

I am new to android development. I need to sync my android application with a calendar. When the calendar events get activated set a notification from my app. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Manifest permissions to read/write calendar.

```
android.permission.READ_CALENDAR
android.permission.WRITE_CALENDAR
```

Put these permissions into your AndroidManifest.xml. Then you will be able to manipulate the content provider used by the default calendar app.

```
calanderURL = "content://com.android.calendar/calendars";  //Calendar
calanderEventURL = "content://com.android.calendar/events";  //Events
calanderRemiderURL = "content://com.android.calendar/reminders"; //Reminders
```

There are many tutorials like [Working with the Android Calendar](http://www.developer.com/ws/android/programming/Working-with-the-Android-Calendar-3850276.htm) on how to work with calendar.

You can read the data from calendar providers and display them in a [CalendarView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html)